# sliderElement.slider is not a function, after magento update

Tags: upgrade, filter, magento2.4.2, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

after magento update from 2.3.4 to 2.4.2, we notice that on sidebar filters, price slide it is not working.

On browser inspect appears those errors:

```
layer.js:406 Uncaught TypeError: sliderElement.slider is not a function
at $.<computed>.<computed>.initSlider (layer.js:406:39)
at $.<computed>.<computed>.initSlider (widget.js:100:41)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._create (layer.js:199:18)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._create (widget.js:100:41)
at $.<computed>.<computed>._createWidget (widget.js:260:18)
at new $.<computed>.<computed> (widget.js:61:22)
at $.<computed>.<computed> (widget.js:55:24)
```

and

```
The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression ''unsafe-inline''
```

There are and other errors, after the upgrade, but I think those two are related with the problem.

Any idea?

Comment: we notice that when disable "Layered Navigation Enable" from store>configuration>Layered Navigation, where is no errors